# Pick the same value of many dictionary in python

Tags: python, json

Recently I was given a problem from an interviewer who gave me a json file which looks like:

```
   {"id:"110235","symbol":"ccl","qty":"900","available":"35500","time":"2016-05-05T08:00:00.169646Z"}
   {"id:"110235","symbol":"ccl","qty":"550","available":"16000","time":"2016-05-05T08:01:05.167356Z"}
   {"id:"110235","symbol":"ssi","qty":"1550","available":"24000","time":"2016-05-05T08:01:07.173386Z"}
   {"id:"110235","symbol":"tcl","qty":"270","available":"21340","time":"2016-05-05T08:01:15.089586Z"}
   {"id:"110235","symbol":"ccl","qty":"690","available":"57840","time":"2016-05-05T08:01:24.236786Z"}
   {"id:"110235","symbol":"tcl","qty":"740","available":"38540","time":"2016-05-05T08:01:28.145786Z"}
```

He wants me to sum the values of all `available` that have the same `symbol`.

I thought about making a set of `symbol`s and loop through the json file and sum the values of `available` but it is slow.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: First write some code that works.  Then make it faster if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way of doing it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(int)
for data in data_set:
   results[data['symbol']] += int(data['available'])

for symbol, total in results.iteritems():
    print('{} - {}'.format(symbol, total))
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what the expected output format is, but if it can be a dictionary the following would be O(n) time.

```
def sum_symbols(data):
    symbols = {}

    for row in data:
        symbol = symbols["symbol"]
        available = int(row["available"])

        if symbol in symbols:
            symbols[symbol] += available
        else:
            symbols[symbol] = available

    return symbols

sum_symbols(data)
```

Comment: can be improved with `collections.defaultdict(int)`

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [{"id": "110235", "symbol": "ccl", "qty": "900", "available": "35500", "time": "2016-05-05T08:00:00.169646Z"},
       {"id": "110235", "symbol": "ccl", "qty": "550", "available": "16000", "time": "2016-05-05T08:01:05.167356Z"},
       {"id": "110235", "symbol": "ssi", "qty": "1550", "available": "24000", "time": "2016-05-05T08:01:07.173386Z"},
       {"id": "110235", "symbol": "tcl", "qty": "270", "available": "21340", "time": "2016-05-05T08:01:15.089586Z"},
       {"id": "110235", "symbol": "ccl", "qty": "690", "available": "57840", "time": "2016-05-05T08:01:24.236786Z"},
       {"id": "110235", "symbol": "tcl", "qty": "740", "available": "38540", "time": "2016-05-05T08:01:28.145786Z"}]

symbols = {}
for a in arr:
    if a["symbol"] in symbols:
        symbols[a["symbol"]] += int(a["available"])
    else:
        symbols[a["symbol"]] = int(a["available"])

print symbols
```